# Parsing JavaScript object to update PostgreSQL tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a JavaScript object as below. I'd like insert the users from this object using a postgres function call in my node.js application. I need help making the postgres function.

I need to check if the user exists, if they do I will alter the user table, if they don't I will insert into the user table.

```
insert: {
  jSmith: {name: 'John Smith', email: 'JSmith@gmail.com'},
  elisa: {name: 'Eli Lisa', email: 'ELisa@gmail.com'}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps work with this other user that has a very similar question?  Are you in the same class?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/62013383/988525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop on the your hash and use postgres `UPSERT` (update or insert). It basically insert a record in to table if there is not any conflict. But if there is any conflict on given constraint it will perform update. for more info: [POSTGRES-UPSERT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)

here is the basic approach for it

```
Object.values(insert).forEach((row) => {
        stmt = `Insert into <table-name> (name, email, other-columns...) values ('${row.name}', '${row.email}', ....)
        On Conflict (name)
        Do
        Update <table-name> set <perform-updating>`

    // Execute the above statement
})
```

You can also make use of prepared statement instead of string interpolation in above algorithm.